# While building cordova project for wp8 through CLI is giving error ERROR: MSBuild tools not found

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild

I am trying to build windows phone 8 project using Cordova CLI command :

```
C:\Cordova build wp8
```

It is giving me error

```
ERROR: MSBuild tools not found
Error: PathTo\MyProject\platforms\wp8\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\pathto\myhomefolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

But the same project when I am building and running using visual studio 2013 for windows software, it is working fine.
I tried to set PATH in system and user setting  environment variable using command

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild
```

after setting PATH also, getting similar error. I tried to restart system and command prompt but it did not bring any result.I have looked other similar question posted in this forum and tried all, but nothing worked.Please advice on this
Currently I am using following software:

1. WIndows OS : 8.1
2. Cordova : 3.6.3-0.2.13

Comment: Please let me know if I need to provide more details to make my question more clear. I have been facing this problem from last 3 days.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I have Windows 8 OS, cordova 4.2.0 and VS 2012 express for Windows Phone installed. I also tried setting path of MSBUILD. but didn't help.